# Teradata Ansi Mode

Tags: database, teradata

I read difference of Teradata and Ansi session mode here: [Link](https://downloads.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/14.11/webhelp/Teradata%20Versus%20ANSI%20Session%20Modes.html). I got that why teradata mode is recommended. But I am confused about that where Ansi mode is used? After all it is an option. It must be used in some scenarios. atleast.

Comment: The following article starts by briefly discussing differences between Teradata and ANSI session modes http://downloads.teradata.com/tools/articles/structuring-requests-in-bteq-for-retryable-and-other-errors

Comment: The default session mode is set on a *server* level (it might be a decision on  company level to adhere more closer to Standard/ANSI SQL) and end users usually don't know/care about the "other" mode. The "official" recommendation is actually ANSI mode but probably 90+ % of all TD systems run in Teradata mode. Some of them might still use ANSI mode for sessions for loading data because it's more picky and will return more errors.